# tvOS buttons created in code cannot be focused

Tags: focus, tvos

Creating my first yellow world style tvOS app and cannot get my first button to work...

No matter what I cannot get this button to be focused. I've tried the same thing in swift with the same result.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    startSlideshowButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50)];
    [startButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:startButton];

    [self setNeedsFocusUpdate];

}

-(UIView*)preferredFocusedView{

    return startButton;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was using the wrong controlEvent

correct:

```
[startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, did you try at iOS11 same code?